# Exception in adapter when trying to inflate layout

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to inflate a layout in my getView method of my adapter:

Here is the error:

```
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:478)
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-18 20:58:04.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21583):    at com.myname.myapp.gui.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:46)
```

The error (according to eclipse happens on the `converView =mInflater...`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent);
    }
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(titles
            .get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the the constructor to my adapter:

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        titles = list;
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any xml file. I thought that was the point of using `android.R.layout...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
```

Yes, you should pass the actual parent because the layout that might affect the parameters used in the inflation. The third parameter, means whether the `inflate` method should add the view to the parent or not.

By default, it will add the view to the parent and in this case you want to return the view but not add it to the parent.

You can read this here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws
>   InflateException if there is an error.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **resource ID** for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
>   R.layout.main_page)
>
> **root**
>     Optional view to be the parent of the
>   generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an
>   object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the
>   returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)
>
> **attachToRoot**  Whether
>   the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If
>   false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of
>   LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.
>
> **Returns** The root View of
>   the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true,
>   this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent);
```

For this one:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
```

Comment: That worked! Why is that? I thought I was supposed to pass in `parent`?

Comment: @EGHDK Pedro Loureiro give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Use below like of code:**

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.demolistlayout,parent,false);
```

Even though it is not fixed then you have to check your layout file.
and mostly it has a problem with drawable images.